# Jenkins unable to start emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I am trying to run the emulator on the Jenkins server. 
But I keep getting this error that Jenkins is unable to start the emulator becoz of the error below until it times out:

```
[android] Waiting 10 seconds before starting emulator...

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 9666 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-arm -ports 9664,9665 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_320_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -no-audio -gpu off

resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 51200 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665
unable to connect to localhost:9665: Connection refused
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:9665
error: no such device 'localhost:9665'
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:9665
error: no such device 'localhost:9665'
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:9665

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:9665 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:9665' not found
```

What should I do to get over this darn issue?

Comment: are you able to fix this issue? I'm running into the same issue and still didn't able to find any fix. Did you find any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that adb was crashing. In my case the cause for the crash was a permission error. Try deleting the file `/tmp/adb.log` before running the job. Please see this thread for more information: [Is it possible to fake a specific path for a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237636/is-it-possible-to-fake-a-specific-path-for-a-process)

You could also add the `-verbose` option to the emulator to see more output that might help.